# What is an easy to follow tutorial on getting EOS staked on REX to start earning passive eos rewards?

Tags: rex, tutorial

I have some EOS staked and would like to just put it on REX as there seems to be a return on just leaving it in the REX without the risk of losing the EOS. Is it really true that you do not lose any of your EOS? If I put in 100 eos into REX, will I get 100 eos back when I withdraw it too?

What are some other downsides to the REX for an EOS holder?

Answer (score 1):

Best is EOS Authority's portal:

https://eosauthority.com/rex

They have a video as well:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD8gvtWve6g

The architecture of the contract is so that you cannot lose your initial input unless the contract is somehow hacked.  When you stake to REX your balance will lower in blocks for your staked CPU amount.  You receive REX tokens which take 4 days to mature at which point you can **SELL** or **HOLD**.  HOLDing will acrue over time and you just have to refresh your vote from time to time.

---

Vote EOS Authority for playing a huge roll in deploying REX which has been a multi-month process.